# How to load UIImageView objects in the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

Is it safe to load `UIImageView` objects in the background, and when done, insert them in the view hierarchy on main thread?

For example you create a GCD block which loads 10 image views in background. At the end you have **async block** which adds all the `UIImageViews` to view hierarchy.

I heard if you create a `UIImage` and add it to a `UIImageView` then the image data gets loaded on demand when the `UIImageView` needs it. How would I force that the `UIImage` data gets pulled in the background so it doesnt block main thread for long loading time?

Comment: Are you downloading these images? Of they're already on disk? Do you see some performance issue (specifically)?

Comment: try [Asyncronous image view](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView) instead of `uiimageView`.

Answer (score 1):

It is always better that if you are downloading images from server you download them on separate thread so It don't block your UI. Once image download complete you can set to that to a specific image view from main thread.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {
        NSData *imageData= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Image_URL];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
           __strong __typeof__(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
           strongSelf.someImageView.image = image;
            ;
        });
    });
```

**NOTE:**
If you are using `AFNetworking`, you can use `UIImageView` category and it will handel loading image in background and also can cache it, so If you want to download again it will bring that image from cache.

Comment: Is it necessary to use __weak self in GCD block??

Comment: Concept is we are not creating any retain cycle. when block is created it will capture its environment means will create strong reference to every object being used in it. So chance to get retian cycle, that's why we use weakself. There is also a chance that if we are in block and no other reference remain then our weak self will be nil, for that we create strongself in side the block. And we also should check for nil before using it.